# Periodically remove packages from hosted NuGet feed on Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager OSS

Tags: nuget, nexus

I'm currently playing around with Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.12.1.

I created a hosted NuGet feed in which all my continous builds should publish their NuGet packages. Now I'm trying to get a scheduled task working which periodically cleans up that feed. I just want to keep the last N versions of each package to avoid that the feed grows indefinitely.

I already tried scheduled tasks of type *Remove Releases From Repository* and *Remove Snapshots From Repository* but both result in an error: 
*The repository ID=XXX is not valid for task*

Comment: Removing items automatically from your feed is generally a bad idea.  If someone depends on an old version of a package, this will break those builds.  Disk space is cheep, use it well.  If package versions are phased out at somepoint, do that in a manual step, not an automatic one.

Comment: I'm aware of that. This feed is only for prerelease builds which I don't want to keep forever...

Comment: There's an existing issue to track this requirement: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6309. It's something we also want to automate on our pre-release feed, as with nightly builds across all of our .NET projects, that cheap disk space soon gets used up.

Comment: Thanks for the link.
As a workaround I found out that it is possible to remove the desired packages on the local file system of the Nexus Server ([NexusInstallDir]\sonatype-work\nexus\storage\ [FeedName]) and then reindex the feed. So it's possible to use a scheduled task of the operating system to cleanup the filesystem and then add a schedule task in Nexus to reindex the feed. This involves a script which may parse the version information of each package. For my requirements it would be enough to just remove the oldest few packages by date...